# Modal behavior between applications

Tags: qt, modal-dialog, parent-child

I have 2 Qt applications. One MDI app and one dialog based app. The dialog based app is started by the other one. I try to simulate a modal parent-child behavior between the applications.
I have a solution, that blocks the user events in the mdi app and handles the hide event in the dialog based app, but this solution blocks showing all other applications which are opened. How could I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Which platforms you want to support? I doubt there's an easily portable solution.